# Passing props to createSwitchNavigator breaks createAppContainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The following code works fine in my expo React Native project:

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Loading:Loading,
    Auth: AuthenticationNavigator,
    Main: MainNavigator
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppContainer/>
    }
}
```

I would like to add `screenProps` to my `createSwitchNavigator`. I used [this example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props). Here is my code:

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Loading:Loading,
    Auth: AuthenticationNavigator,
    Main: MainNavigator
});
const AppNavigatorWithProps=(<AppNavigator screenProps={{testing:true}} />)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigatorWithProps);

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppContainer/>
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.router.getStateForAction')

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:42)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer screenProps={{ testing: true }} />
   }
 }
```

Like this

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to wrap `AppNavigator` with `createAppContainer` or anything else,

simply use zhou Dai answer like below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppNavigator screenProps={{
          //pass any object you need for ex
          testing:true
        }}/>
    }
}
```

but I add another information for using the props like below:

for access those props, you can simply use:

```
console.log(this.props.screenProps.testing)
```

on any screen defined in `createSwtichNavigator`,

for example in your code:

`Loading, Auth, and Main` should get the props

```
class Loading extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount(){
      console.log(this.props.screenProps.testing)
    }
    render() {
        return (<View/>)
    }
}
```

> **Note:**
>   I have test the code using `React Navigation V2`